# Making changes in the hadoop source code

Tags: hadoop

I've tried importing Apache Hadoop Source code in Eclipse. Is it possible that I can debug how Hadoop works by running it as an Eclipse project itself? Once the modification is complete, how should I deploy it and check?What is the procedure to be followed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You first need to download hadoop source code(version which you want).
- Install **Maven 3.0, ProtocolBuffer 2.5.0, CMake 2.6 or newer (if compiling native code)**
  There is a "Building.txt" file in source code. All requirements
  needed for building code is given. Follow it. Read complete file. You will understand much more things
- Run Following commands after installing above

> $ mvn install -DskipTests
>
> $ mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true

- Now your project is Eclipse ready.

> 1.File -> Import...
>
> 2.Choose "Existing Projects into Workspace".
>
> 3.Select hadoop src folder as root 
>   4. Click "Finish"

Check out this link [HowToContribute](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute)

Comment: I successfully imported Hadoop source code to Eclipse. How should I proceed next? Is it possible to run Hadoop from Eclipse? Because, unless I know where the code exists which has to be modified, I would be clueless on how to modify.